# ActiveRecord validation: maximum length of one symbol to be value minus length of another symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two symbols, the values of which are set by the user.

I need to validate the length of them. The maximum length of each symbol needs to be 32 minus the length of the other symbol.

I've written it like so so far but this does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions for how this could work?

```
validates :id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :name }, length: { maximum: 32 - :name.length }
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :id }, length: { maximum: 32 - :id.length }
```

NB: I am only a graduate, so there's a big chance i've done this totally wrong because I'm still learning and don't really understand symbols yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a custom validation here:

```
validates :id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :name }
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :id }
validate :name_and_id_max_length

def name_and_id_max_length
  if (id || '').length + (name || '').length > 32
    errors.add(:base, "id and name combined must be 32 or fewer characters")
  end
end
```

Btw: Usually `id` in Rails is an integer, but you seem to be treating it as a string. That suggests some other confusion.

Also `:id.length` is not valid Ruby. In these `validates` declarations you are calling *class* methods, so there is no instance with an `id` yet. To do arithmetic against actual values you'd need a proc. Rails doesn't support this here AFAIK, but in other contexts it's a useful pattern to embed snippets of per-instance computation that you declare at the class level:

```
validates :name, length: { maximum: proc { 32 - id.length } }
```

For instance for a real example:

```
scope :recent, -> { where("created_at > ?", 24.hours.ago) }
```

Comment: I think you should write `id.to_s`.

Comment: Also uniqueness of `id` validation is unnecessary.. :) uniqueness on `name` is fine..no need to scope it with `id`..

Comment: As @Arup asys, if `id` is in fact your primary key, as is normal in Rails, adding `{ scope :id }` to the uniqueness constraint on `name` is wrong, because two identical names will always be "unique" due to their different `id`s.